# Basic authentification ignoring password validation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I configure WebSecurityConfig, create user in memory

```
@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("username")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
                .authorities("READ_ORDERS")
                .roles("USER");
    }
```

configure WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class BasicAuthenticationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private final AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        public BasicAuthenticationAdapter(AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint) {
            this.authEntryPoint = authEntryPoint;
        }

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/orders**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        }
    }
```

When i try to Authorise with invalid credentials first time - 401 exception, it's ok.
But after successful authorization, when i use invalid username and password,
i also authorised.
What can be the problem ?

Comment: is your previous user still logged in? did you close the session?

Comment: @Stultuske i just send requests via postman
Btw, how can i check?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980247/spring-security-authentication-success-with-wrong-password

Comment: it's wrong configuration. it's need to configure antMatchers afte antMather http
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .antMatcher("/orders/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/orders/**").hasRole("READ_ORDERS")

Answer (score 0):

That is how basic authentication works. As soon as you have logged in successfully the valid credentials will always be posted.

Spring security works with SessionCreationPolicy, and default policy is IF_REQUIRED. It means spring creates session if it does not have and is required.

In order to solve your issue you have to change this policy.

```
http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

Restart your server and try again.